# Google AdSense in Android without website

Tags: android, adsense

I'm about to upload an application on Google Play and I want Google Ads in it, but to apply you must enter a website and I don't have one. Is it possible to register in some other way without making a blog or something just because you want the adsense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a Facebook Page for your app and use the URL for that.  You may want one in the future for marketing purposes, anyway.

There isn't a way to get around providing some sort of website address - you will need at least some form of a website (whether it's a blog, facebook page, or your own domain) in order to register.

Comment: Is AdSense the best way to display ads in Android apps?

Comment: I'm not certain - I'd imagine so.  Their top competitor used to be AdMob and they bought them, so I think AdSense in Android is a safe bet.

Comment: Does it work with a Twitter-account? Or is it better with a Facebook page?

Comment: Either works.  I think you'll get more shares from Facebook though.